# Selected and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that at the click on a single element (#add_text) adds content (#text_frame) inside another element (#template) and this element (#text_frame) can be dragged.

```
$('#add_text').mousedown
  (
   function() 
   {                              
    $('#add_text').css('background-color', 'blue'),
    $('#template').prepend('<div id="text_frame"></div>'), 
    $('#text_frame').draggable('enable'), 
    $('#text_frame').draggable  ({containment:'#safe_area',distance:1});
   }
  );
```

How to do that by clicking on an added element he stood out, such as its border was a different color and by pressing the other button to remove the text for example adding an item is removed?

---

**Update**: this is the complete code in flavor of an SSCCE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />


    <title>Add/Delete</title>

<style type="text/css">

div#template
{
  position: relative; outline: 1px #B7C4CE solid; 
        width: 556px; height: 320px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; 
} 

div#text_frame
    {
        position:absolute; outline:1px silver solid; background-color:#F7F9FC; width: 96px;
        height:24px; margin-top: 34px; margin-left: 32px; cursor: pointer;                  
    } 

div#add_text,div#delete_text
    {    
  position: relative; 
        outline:1px silver solid; background-color:red; width: 99px; height: 20px;
        margin-top: 15px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;    
    } 
</style> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  /* ------------------- add_text --------------------*/

    $('#add_text').hover
        (
            function() {$('#add_text').css('outline', '1px blue solid');}, 
            function() {$('#add_text').css('outline', '1px silver solid');}                     
        );

   $('#add_text').mousedown
        (
            function() 
            {                              
                $('#add_text').css('background-color', 'blue'),
    $('#template').prepend('<div id="text_frame"></div>'), 
                $('#text_frame').draggable('enable'), 
    $('#text_frame').draggable({containment: '#safe_area', distance: 1});    
            }         
        );  

   $('#add_text').mouseup
        (
            function() 
            {                              
                $('#add_text').css('background-color', 'red');
            }         
        );   

  /* ------------------- select_delete_text --------------------*/

    $('#delete_text').hover
        (
            function() {$('#delete_text').css('outline', '1px blue solid');}, 
            function() {$('#delete_text').css('outline', '1px silver solid');}                     
        );

   $('#delete_text').mousedown
        (
            function() 
            {                              
                $('#delete_text').css('background-color', 'blue')  
            }         
        );  

   $('#delete_text').mouseup
        (
            function() 
            {                              
                $('#delete_text').css('background-color', 'red');
            }         
        );    

   $('#text_frame').click // dont work ???
        (
            function() 
            {                              
                $('#text_frame').css('outline', '1px black solid'); 
            }         
        );          
}); 

 </script>

</head>

<body>

     <div id="template"></div> 

        <div id="add_text" class="font_button">add elements</div>         
        <div id="delete_text" class="font_button">delete elements</div> 

<br /><br />1) Press the button several times "add elements"<br />
2) drag items<br /><br />

how to make:<br /><br />
1) Select Item<br />
2) change of style (outline color for example) element when it is selected<br />
3) Remove the chosen item by pressing the button "delete elements"<br />

</body>
</html>
```

I am using jQuery with jQuery UI.

Comment: I don't know the solution to your question (as I don't really understand what you are asking) but a quick tip when posting on Stack Overflow: try to tag your questions appropriately. I added the jQuery and JavaScript tags. The ones you had, 'remove' and 'selected', don't really tell anyone what the question is about. Also it would be helpful to indicate in your post that you are using JavaScript with the jQuery framework along with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var newNode = $('<div></div>').attr('id','text_frame').css('border','1px solid red');
$('#template').prepend(newNode);
```